# Odds of Not Rolling a 3 After 80 Rolls of 2 Dice

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Can someone tell me what the odds of not rolling a total of 3 on two dice (that is, a combination of 1 and 2 that totals 3) after 80 rolls of the dice? Each die is 6 sided (your typical dice) with 1 through 6 on each side.

I played an electronic game where after 80 rolls, the total of the 2 dice never totaled 3. I thought this was very unusual and that the odds were astronomical of a total 3 not being rolled after 80 rolls of the 2 dice.

However, I inquired of the maker of the electronic game, and this was their customer service’s response to me:

“Not that I happen to be a mathematician, I calculated the corresponding probability:
​
Of the total 36 possible rolls are only 2 that add up to 3.
The probability of rolling anything but a 3 is 17/18.
(17/18)^80 = 0.010330309

This means that such an event occurs about once every 100 games. I would not call this ‘astronomical’.
​;-)”

Is their calculation of the odds correct ... is it really so that you can roll 2 dice 80 times in a row, and a total combination of 3 not be rolled every 100 games?

Thanks for any input ...

Comment: Yes, that calculation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of not rolling a total of $3$ is $\displaystyle \frac{17}{18}$, and for $80$ rolls, $\displaystyle \left (\frac{17}{18} \right)^{80}$ is correctly calculated. Good work.